# Getting segmentation fault (core dump) for binary search(recursive) to find a number in an array

Tags: c++, recursion, binary-search

This is a problem to find the target number in an array using the binary search recursive method.
**Getting segmentation fault.**
Have tried a lot but cannot find what is causing it.
need some help to avoid such mistakes.
which part is wrong in my code??
I have pasted the complete code.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std ;


int recursivebinarysearch(vector <int>& arr ,int target , int ans ){
    int high = arr.size() - 1 ;
    int low = 0 ;
    int mid = (high + low) / 2 ;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < arr.size() ; i++){
        
        mid = (low+high)/2 ;
        if(low > high){
            mid = -1;
            return mid;
        }
        if(target > arr[mid]){
            low = mid +1 ;
            recursivebinarysearch(arr ,  target , ans );
        }
        else if(target < arr[mid]){
            high = mid -1;
            recursivebinarysearch(arr , target , ans );
        }
        else{
            mid = ans ;
            return ans ;
        }
    }
}
int main(){
    int n,   target , ans = 0;
    
    cin >> n  ;
    
    vector<int> arr ;
    int j = 0;
    for(int j = 0 ; j < n ; j++){
        cin >> arr[j];
    }
    cin >> target ;
    sort(arr.begin() , arr.end());
    ans = recursivebinarysearch(arr,  target , ans);

    cout<<ans<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't tag irrelevant languages.

Comment: In `recursivebinarysearch(arr , target , ans )`, you call `recursivebinarysearch(arr , target , ans )`. To be clear, you pass the *exact same* arguments. This makes no sense. And you eventually run out of stack space.

Comment: You create a vector called arr containing no elements & then try to access elements in it. Rather, you want to add elements to it. probably by using arr.push_back(). Or you could size it to contain N elements to start & then modify those element to new values.

Comment: @ikegami Exactly!

Comment: A binary search is trivially recursive (requires tail recursion only), and is basically just a loop.  Typically the arguments to the search function include the beginning and end of the relevant range of the array to search.  Yours does not.  Each time the search is called, the search range is presumably the entire range again.  This does nothing to progressively refine the range.  You undoubtedly get a stack overflow as the array size never changes.

Comment: @Avi Berger, Are you saying `cin >> arr[j]` doesn't add to the vector?

Comment: Yes, that is what I'm saying. It changes the j-th element - only there isn't one yet. That is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`high`, `low`, `mid` are local to your function. So, each time you call `recursivebinarysearch` with the same vector `arr`, you get the same values. So, you infinitely recurse. The segmentation fault happens when the stack overflows.

If you want to keep this approach, you need to pass `high` and `mid` to the function and have it search this range only.

Alternatively, you can have a single `while` and adjust local values `high`, `low` as you go. This would be better, but some professors out there want to see explicit recursion.

Also, thanks to the comments,
`cin >> arr[j];` doesn't work. Either:

```
int value;
cin >> value;
arr.push_back(value);
```

or

```
arr.resize(j+1);
cin >> arr[j];
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all I do not understand why are you trying to implement binary search using recursion, when the standard implementation below is O(logN).

And as [ikegami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589924/ikegami) and [Jeffry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4474230/jeffrey) mentioned, you are recursively iterating without any change in arguments, so you eventually exhaust the stack, and cause segmentation fault.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#define NOT_FOUND -1

int not_a_recursivebinarysearch(const std::vector<int> &v, const int x)
{
    std::vector<int>::size_type low = 0;
    std::vector<int>::size_type high = v.size() - 1;
    while(low <= high)
    {
        std::vector<int>::size_type mid = (low + high) / 2;
        if(v[mid] < x)
            low = mid + 1;
        else if(v[mid] > x)
            high = mid - 1;
        else
            return mid;
    }
    return NOT_FOUND;
}
```

And as [Avi Berger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/631266/avi-berger) mentioned in comments, your logic to populate the vector is not correct either. C++ vectors use standard C type arrays under the hood, but they claim more capacity dynamically. Ofcourse, this can only happen when you use the right interface such as: `vector_name.push_back`.

```cpp
int main(){
    int n, target, ans = 0;
    int temp;
    
    cin >> n;
    
    vector<int> arr;

    // int j = 0;
    // This is not needed
    // The following loop already init-declares `j`

    for(int j = 0; j < n; ++j){
        cin >> temp;
        arr.push_back(temp);
    }
    cin >> target;
    sort(arr.begin() , arr.end());
    ans = not_a_recursivebinarysearch(arr, target);

    cout << ans << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

A small improvement would be to check for `-1` returned from `recursivebinarysearch`, and show a more meaningful result to user.

```cpp
ans = not_a_recursivebinarysearch(arr, target)
if(ans == -1) cout << "NOT FOUND" << endl;
else cout << "FOUND at index: " << ans << endl;
```